# How linux passwd command is making sure that it can't modify other user's password from an unprivileged account

Tags: linux, permissions, passwd

I know, `passwd` has `setuid` bit set and hence it can modify `root` owned `/etc/shadow` file.

```
[~]$ ls -l `which passwd`
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 27832 Jan 29  2014 /usr/bin/passwd
```

But how it is making sure that it can modify only the current account's password if logged in as a non-root user.

Answer (score 0):

There are additional UID/GID values available via the geteuid() and similar.  The effective UID is the one for whatever user started the program.  All the setuid privilege is used for is to change the runtime credentials to that of the effective UID/GUI.  Then normal permissions apply.